# How to show that $f:V\to V$ is linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $(V,|.|)$ be a normed finite dimensional vector space and $f:V\to V$ a map with the following property:

- $|f(y)|=|f(x+y)-f(x)|,\quad \forall x, y\in V.$

Then how to prove that $f$ is linear?

**Update:** what can be say if $V$ is a real vector space?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Hint: in such problems it's often useful to pick some trivial value for one of $x$ or $y$, such as $0$, because that often gives you a condition in *one* variable that's very useful.

Comment: I know this fact and I tried this: $|f(y)|=|f(y)-f(0)|$ so $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Everyone is jumping on the additive to linear gap, but the more interesting question is: Is every function that satisfies this equation additive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without specifying the base field this is false even if we interprete "map" as continuous:
Consider $\Bbb C$ with standard norm as one-dimensional complex vector space and let $f(z)=\overline z$.

Comment: If we consider just real vector spaces then is the answer affirmative?

Answer (score 5):

This is false. Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be an additive function. Then the hypothesis is satisfied. But without some continuity/measurability assumption we cannot conclude that $f$ is linear.

Comment: "map" might mean "continuous function" in this context.