# If $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ satisfies $\|f(x - y)\| = \|f(x) - f(y)\|$, is $f$ additive?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, functional-equations

## Question

Main question:

> Let $\| \cdot \|$ be a norm on a finite-dimensional real vector space $V$. If $f : V \to V$ is a function satisfying
>   $$
> \| f(x-y)\| = \|f(x) - f(y)\|
> $$
>   for all $x, y \in V$, does it follow that $f$ is additive? I.e., does it follow that $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all $x, y$?

Follow-up:

> Does the answer change depending on the choice of $\| \cdot \|$? In particular, what if $\| \cdot \|$ is an inner product norm?

## Background

Last week, user C.F.G. asked [a very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301334/how-to-show-that-fv-to-v-is-linear), to which the answer was "no for trivial reasons": they asked whether the function $f$ was necessarily linear, but clearly all additive functions satisfy the condition, and there are non-linear additive functions. User Charlie Cunningham pointed out in the comments that the question is actually interesting if you remove the trivial reasons. Because the question had been answered, I [tried to get an answer to the non-trivial question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3303545/are-f-satisfying-fy-fxy-fx-additive/) myself. The original question included the requirement that the vector space be finite-dimensional; I removed this requirement because it erroneously struck me as an irrelevant restriction (I thought you could just take the subspace containing $x, y, f(x), f(y)$ to get a finite-dimensional $V$). (The functional relation in those questions has a different form, but this is equivalent the formulation above, as pointed out by user Omnomnomnom in comments.)

However, we then got [a negative answer to my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3303622/75429) -- an example of a non-additive $f$ satisfying the condition -- where the infinite-dimensionality of $V$ was crucial. This has left us with the tantalizing option that the finite-dimensionality of $V$ was crucial to the resolution of the question. I did not want to ask yet another very similar question here, but I also did not want to edit my question, as it had gotten a correct answer that did not deserve to be made irrelevant. Maybe third time's the charm?

Comment: What if $f(x+y)=f(x)-f(y)$? Doesn’t this functional equation also satisfy the norm equation??

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης, sure it does, but the only $f$ satisfying that equation is the 0 function. To see this, just take $x = y = 0$ to conclude that $f(0) = 0$, and then take $x = 0$ to see that $f(y) = -f(y)$.

Comment: Can we solve it for $n=1$?  Then we have, for each $x,y$ either $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ or $f(x+y)=f(x)-f(y)$.  Choice of sign depends on $x,y$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Ah indeed I see! I wrote it in a hurry and didn't realize

Comment: We can write your equation as 
$$
\|f([x + y] - [x])\| = \|f(x+y) - f(x)\|
$$
that is, your condition is equivalent to stating that
$$
\|f(x-y)\| = \|f(x) - f(y)\|
$$
for all $x,y \in V$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim does not hold. The classical counterexample mentioned in the linked answer by GEdgar works.

Let $V=\mathbb R^2$ supplied with the max-norm. Define $f$ by
$$
f(x) = (x_1, |x_1|).
$$
Then
$$
\|f(x-y)\| = |x_1-y_1|
$$
and
$$
\|f(x) - f(y)\| = \max (|x_1-y_1|, \ \big||x_1|-|y_1|\big|) = |x_1-y_1|,
$$
so the condition is satisfied but $f$ is not additive.